# Show Base Class throws error if base class is generic and in a class library

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2015, com, class-diagram

Say I have a class library project (`Library`) which contains a class of:

```
Public Class SomeClass(Of TTypeA, TTypeB)
```

Then, in another project `UIProject` in a different solution, I define a class that is derived from (inherits) SomeClass:

```
Imports Library
Public Class SomeDerivedClass
Inherits SomeClass(Of String, Boolean)
```

I have included Library.pdb and Library.xml alongside Library.dll (in the same folder) when I added the class libary reference to the `UIProject`.

Now, In `UIProject` I create a ClassDiagram (ClassDiagram1.cd), and add in the `SomeClass` class. So far so good.

The next step is to right-click on `SomeClass` in the diagram, and select "Show Base Class" from the dropdown. At this point, I am given the error:

> Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM
>   component.

If I do the same but for a non-generic version of `SomeClass`, then `SomeClass` is included in the class diagram, no problem.

No errors show up in ActivityLog.xml; nor in the Windows Event Viewer.

Is this a bug in Visual Studio (in which case I'll report it); or am I doing something wrong (and if so are there any other error logs or traces I can do to narrow down the issue further)?

Comment: AFAIK, COM does not work with generic types.  Since VS uses a lot of COM under the hood, you may be out of luck.  I suggest that you add the COM tag to get exposure from those with that specific knowledge.

Comment: I couldn't reproduce the problem using VS2017(version 15.5) it works properly.

Comment: @RezaAghaei, TnTinMn; Seeing as no-one else is answering, why don't you write that as an answer; and if no-one else can give a better answer in the next 8 hours one of you'll get the bounty

Comment: @simonalexander2005 Did you try that in VS2017?

Comment: I don't have 2017 installed so I can't test that - 2015's the version I'm working with currently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer seems to be that COM does not work with generic types; and that it works in VS2017.